# Order Query by Parent and Child

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing a query and i want to order via parent and subParent, but i have a problem. Isn't ordering right.

Heres my Query

```
    WITH CLASSIFICATION_LIST AS
(
    SELECT SUBPARENT.[ID], SUBPARENT.[NAME], SUBPARENT.[PARENTID], 
           1 AS LEVELCLASSIFICATION, SUBPARENT.[ID] AS HIERARCHY,
           SUBPARENT.[ISACTIVE]
    FROM {Classification} AS SUBPARENT
    WHERE SUBPARENT.[PARENTID] IS NULL
    AND (@ShowAll = 1 OR SUBPARENT.ISACTIVE = 1)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CHILD.[ID], CHILD.[NAME], CHILD.[PARENTID],
            EL.LEVELCLASSIFICATION+1 , EL.HIERARCHY,  CHILD.[ISACTIVE]
    FROM {Classification} AS CHILD    
             INNER JOIN CLASSIFICATION_LIST AS EL ON CHILD.[PARENTID] = EL.[ID]
    WHERE CHILD.[PARENTID] IS NOT NULL
    AND (@ShowAll = 1 OR CHILD.ISACTIVE = 1)

)
SELECT *
FROM CLASSIFICATION_LIST
ORDER BY 5,4,1
```

Heres the query output:

[image: Query Output]

The correct output is:

```
Teste
  Filho 1
  Filho 2
Computador
  Motherboard
  Grafica
      Memoria
  Memoria
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of ordering by the Column Ordinal, you should order by the column name, as it is easier to read and less prone to breaking if you change the Column Ordinals

Comment: Please use the name in the ORDER BY clause instead of the ordnial position. Usage of ordinal position in an ORDER BY clause is considered bad practice and decrease readability.

Comment: If you could provide us with a sample dataset it would be easier to trouble shoot. My gut feeling is you need to remove your order by all together, The recursive CTE should take care of it.

Comment: Agreed with @Abris - please [read this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please notice that you are ordering by 5,4,1 i.e. in your case hierarchy, Level and then Classification Id.
If you notice keenly, you'll see that in the marked records, ordering is because of difference in level.

So if you wanted them ordered in different manner probably only by Classification Id, you should use `ORDER BY 1`

Comment: Or even better `ORDER BY ClassificationID`